# Woocommerce filter catgory VS tag VS attribute, When to use what?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, filter

** I'm using the term category in the question just so I can explain the issue.

I'm working on a WordPress shoe affiliate catalog (not a store).
The main feature of the website is a massive filter option with filtering combination options.

I'm using WOOF filter plugin for the sidebar filter.

Have divided the products into many categories, all items have and are sharing more than one category.
Users should be able to select as many filters as he wants.

Can someone please tell me what is the best way to map filters?

Example of categories:
Lacing System,
Materials,
Eco friendly,
Usage,
Gender,
Season,
Terrien, 
type,
color,
size,
Weight

And a few more...

what should I use, category, tag or attribute?